# How does user input echo back over SSH sessions?

Tags: ssh

In a SSH session, when we press some keys, they will be echoed back to the terminal.

How does it happen? Does the SSH client itself do the job? Or, each time some keys are pressed, some packets are sent over the network to the server, and the server sent back some other packets to tell the client to adjust characters displayed on the terminal?

I think the latter one is too inefficient to be realistic. But I am not sure. Can someone help?

Comment: [Research material](https://serverfault.com/a/302542).

Comment: It's the latter of course. Instead of asking, run `tcpdump port 22`.

Comment: Thanks! Your help is appreciated! I think you guys are right.